# Angular 8 Dropdown Options Default Last New Value After Update ArrayList

Tags: angular, nebular

I am using Angular 8 (TypeScript).

I want to select by default the last value agregated in array collection after call service and update the value of array, But always show the placeholder. How can I do it?

```
<nb-select [(selected)]="selectedNumberCase" 
           placeholder="Select value" shape="round" size="small" 
            class="col-md-7 custom-padding" >
    <nb-option *ngFor="let item of caseNumberArray" (click)="onMenuItemSelected(item.value)"[value]="item.id">{{item.value}}</nb-option>
</nb-select>


populateNumberCase(newId:string,newValue:string){
    this.caseNumberArray.push({
        id:element.newId,
        value:element.newValue
    });
}

callService(){
    .......do something
    this.populateNumberCase(result.Id,result.Value);
    this.selectedNumberCase = result.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Assuming You will be having the array object in this variable
Just

Ininitalize a variable;

```
selectedOption;
```

copy the below line in ngOnit() function.

```
this.selectedOption= this.selectedNumberCase[this.selectedNumberCase.length-1];
```

Template Code::

```
<nb-select [(selected)]="selectedOption" placeholder="Select value" shape="round" size="small" 
            class="col-md-7 custom-padding" >
      <nb-option
        *ngFor="let item of caseNumberArray"
        (selectionChange)="onMenuItemSelected(item.value)"
        [(value)]="item.id">
        {{ item.value}}
      </nb-option>
    </nb-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. If it doesn't work, try replacing  "selectionChange" with "change"

```
<nb-select [(selected)]="selectedNumberCase" placeholder="Select value" shape="round" size="small" 
            class="col-md-7 custom-padding" >
      <nb-option
        *ngFor="let item of caseNumberArray"
        (selectionChange)="onMenuItemSelected(item.value)"
        [(value)]="item.id">
        {{ item.value}}
      </nb-option>
    </nb-select>
```

Comment: It not shows the last value for example I have this collection [{id: '1',value:'CT001'}, {id: '2',value:'CT002'}, {id:'3',value:'CT003'}], but whe I pressed a button the collection changes to   [{id: '1',value:'CT001'}, {id: '2',value:'CT002'}, {id:'3',value:'CT003'}, {id:'4',value:'CT004'}] I want to select by default the last value (CT004).

Comment: you should not duplicate answer. add answer option in same one.